# Failed to build quarkus application -transformed-bytecode.jar

Tags: quarkus

unable to build quarkus application
quarkus-maven-plugin:2.10.0.Final
[ERROR] Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to create a new filesystem for \target\quarkus-app\quarkus\transformed-bytecode.jar
[ERROR]         at io.quarkus.fs.util.ZipUtils.newZip(ZipUtils.java:133)
[ERROR]         at io.quarkus.deployment.pkg.steps.JarResultBuildStep.buildThinJar(JarResultBuildStep.java:611)
[ERROR]         at io.quarkus.deployment.pkg.steps.JarResultBuildStep.buildRunnerJar(JarResultBuildStep.java:218)
[ERROR]         at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[ERROR]         at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
[ERROR]         at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[ERROR]         at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
[ERROR]         at io.quarkus.deployment.ExtensionLoader$3.execute(ExtensionLoader.java:944)
[ERROR]         ... 6 more
[ERROR] Caused by: java.nio.file.FileSystemException: \target\quarkus-app\quarkus\transformed-bytecode.jar: Operation did not complete successfully because the file contains a virus or potentially unwanted software.
[ERROR]
[ERROR]         at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(WindowsException.java:92)
[ERROR]         at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:103)
[ERROR]         at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:108)
[ERROR]         at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.checkReadAccess(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:343)
[ERROR]         at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.checkAccess(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:367)
[ERROR]         at jdk.zipfs/jdk.nio.zipfs.ZipFileSystem.(ZipFileSystem.java:108)
[ERROR]         at jdk.zipfs/jdk.nio.zipfs.ZipFileSystemProvider.newFileSystem(ZipFileSystemProvider.java:106)
[ERROR]         at io.quarkus.fs.util.ZipUtils.newZip(ZipUtils.java:130)
[ERROR]         ... 13 more

Answer (score 0):

This seems like an issue with an overzealous virus scanning software.

You can't turn off the creation of that jar when using fast-jar.

You will likely have to turn off or tune your antivirus software